# Security question: excessive Drupal requests from a single user account

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-6, brute-force, denial-of-service

I've notice some strange behaviour on my Drupal site. I like to understand the data I'm looking at before I take action so that I don't waste time pursuing the wrong measures, but I'm lacking security knowledge to interpret.

A single account has made many odd repeat requests, including attempting to reach the edit profile page, logging in (successfully - someone noticed the account had 250 active sessions a few days ago), and a huge number of password requests. The account does not have admin rights, and anyone can register for an account.

EDIT: Drupal version is 6.17.

My best guesses at what is going on are as follows:

(1) Joe Evil-doer is using multiple reset password requests as a DOS attack (it's working :< )

(2) Joe Evil-doer is trying to somehow build up a dictionary of possible passwords from his repeated requests (I don't see a way that this would work).

(3) I am a victim of a bunch of transactions failing and attempting to recommit many times over.

Any other scenarios? Does any of this match with up with common Drupal exploits?

Here's the data. I ran the following query on the accesslog table in my database:

```
select count(*), title, path from accesslog where uid = 999 group by title, path;
```

With the results below (user ID and page names cleaned up, ofc). Count(*) in each column should indicate the number of requests received for each operation.

```
+----------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| count(*) | title                   | path                                     |
+----------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|       16 |                         | home                                     | 
|     1334 | Access denied           | user/999/edit                            | 
|      184 | Series                  | events/series                            | 
|        1 | Home                    | user/register                            | 
|        1 | Reset password          | user/reset/999/123124/a2340a1c1123/login | 
|        1 | username                | user/999                                 |   
|        5 | username                | user/999/edit                            | 
|        1 | username                | user/me                                  | 
|      904 | User account            | user/login                               | 
|    11252 | User account            | user/password                            | 
|      288 | User account            | user/register                            | 
|        1 | Validate e-mail address | user/validate/999/1283452346/a0f123459e  | 
+----------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Good question,  do you have any traffic captured from this attack?

Comment: Also what is the exact Drupal version that you are running?  No one can help you without this.

Comment: any captured data using IDS, we can analyze

Comment: No traffic info unfortunately - we have added some logging to the box now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's some sort of no 1. Reset password is only helpful if you have the email and you only need to do it once. I don't think 3 is even possible.

It's pretty easy to fix. For some sites I do this by default. With hook_menu_alter you can remove the menu item for the password reset. It will make it impossible for all users to reset their password.

An other option would be to include a CAPTCHA on the form since it's most likely a bot doing this. Should be pretty easy with an existing module.

Comment: Turns out the Drupal captcha and recaptcha modules are the bomb-diggity. Extremely simple to install.

Answer (score 1):

You may look see if the logins are scheduled.  If it is a bot the logins may be every 24 hours to the second, eg.  A security specialist administering a site would probably delete the account to avert the attack.  If it is an ecomm site inform the owner that their account has been flagged for security.  Ask them to create a new account.  Lock and then delete the existing account.  Ask owner to do a credit check.